# I can't get text in Titanium tables

Tags: text, titanium, tableview

I'm pretty new to Titanium and I have to do this for a school project. Anyway I can't get text to show itself in tables. Help! 
This is my code:

```
// resourcesDirectory is actually the default location, so the first 
// argument could be omitted here.
var file = Ti.Filesystem.getFile(Ti.Filesystem.resourcesDirectory, "textfile.txt");
var filet1 = Ti.Filesystem.getFile(Ti.Filesystem.resourcesDirectory, "table1.txt");
var filet2 = Ti.Filesystem.getFile(Ti.Filesystem.resourcesDirectory,     "http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=JDCZyfw3");

//http://www.google.com/humans.txt

var xhr = Titanium.Network.createHTTPClient();
xhr.open("GET","http://www.google-analytics.com/ga.js");
xhr.onload = function(){
  // check status of connection to server
statusCode = xhr.status;
    //check the response code returned
    if(statusCode == 200)
    {
    var doc = this.responseText;
//write data from downloaded text file to local text file
    var f =  Titanium.Filesystem.getFile(Titanium.Filesystem.applicationDataDirectory,'test.txt');
        f.write(doc);
    }

    };
xhr.send();
//-----------------------------------------------------------------------
//---------------------local file read---------------------------------------
var f = Titanium.Filesystem.getFile(Titanium.Filesystem.applicationDataDirectory,         'test.txt');


// read the file into contents var    
//var contents = f.read();

// print out contents of file 
//Ti.API.info('contents = ' + contents.text);

//-----------------------------------------------------------------------
//--------------------------end of file read--------------------------
var content = file.read();
var content2 = f.read();
// this sets the background color of the master UIView (when there are no windows/tab groups              on it)
 Titanium.UI.setBackgroundColor('#DCE6F2');
    // create tab group
  var tabGroup = Titanium.UI.createTabGroup();


var win1 = Titanium.UI.createWindow({  
    title:"Niveau's",
    backgroundColor:'#DCE6F2',
    window: win1
});

 var header= Titanium.UI.createView({
    backgroundImage:'logo.jpg',
    //backgroundColor: 'black', 
    top: 0, left:0, 
    height:65, width:320
}); 
//win1.add(header);


var tab3 = Titanium.UI.createWindow({  
    title:'Leerwegen',
    backgroundColor:'#DCE6F2',
        window: win3
});
var tab4 = Titanium.UI.createWindow({  
    title:'Instellingen',
    backgroundColor:'#DCE6F2',
        window: win4
});


var data = [
{title:'Niveau 2', hasChild:true, dest:'C:\Users\Rick\Documents\Titanium_Studio_Workspace\mbo app pdh\Resources\Car_1.js'},
{title:'Niveau 3', hasChild:true, dest:'C:\Users\Rick\Documents\Titanium_Studio_Workspace\mbo app pdh\Resources\Car_2.js'},
{title:'Niveau 4', hasChild:true, dest:'C:\Users\Rick\Documents\Titanium_Studio_Workspace\mbo app pdh\Resources\Car_3.js'}
];

var table = Ti.UI.createTableView({
data: data
});

table.addEventListener('click', function(e){
if (e.rowData.hasChild) {
    var newWin = Ti.UI.createWindow({

    url: e.rowData.url,//dest
    title:  e.rowData.title,
    backgroundColor: '#DCE6F2'
});
tab1.open(newWin);
}
});

var view = Ti.UI.createView();
view.add(table);
win1.add(view);

var label1 = Titanium.UI.createLabel({
color:'#999',
text:filet2,
font:{fontSize:20,fontFamily:'Helvetica Neue'},
textAlign:'center',
width:'auto'
});

var label2 = Titanium.UI.createLabel({
color:'#999',
text: content2,
font:{fontSize:20,fontFamily:'Helvetica Neue'},
textAlign:'left',
    width:'auto'
    });

//
// create controls tab and root window
//
    var win2 = Titanium.UI.createWindow({  
    title:'Domeinen',
    backgroundColor:'#DCE6F2'
    });
    var win3 = Titanium.UI.createWindow({  
    title:'Leerwegen',
    backgroundColor:'#DCE6F2'
    });
    var win4 = Titanium.UI.createWindow({  
    title:'Instellingen',
    backgroundColor:'#DCE6F2'
    });


    var tab3 = Titanium.UI.createTab({  
    title:'Leerwegen',
   // backgroundColor:'#DCE6F2',
       window:win3
    });
    var tab4 = Titanium.UI.createTab({  
    title:'Instellingen',
   window:win4
    });
    var tab2 = Titanium.UI.createTab({  
  // icon:'KS_nav_ui.png',
  title:'Domeinen',
  window:win2
    });


var tab1 = Ti.UI.createTab({
title:  "Niveau's",
window: win1
});

win2.add(label2);
win1.add(label1);


//
//  add tabs
//
tabGroup.addTab(tab1);  
tabGroup.addTab(tab2); 
tabGroup.addTab(tab3); 
tabGroup.addTab(tab4);  
tabGroup.open();
```

This is my table file (car_3.js)

```
var view_car_3 = Ti.UI.createView();

var label_car_3 = Ti.UI.createlabel({
text: 'lorum ipsum nogwat',
height: 35,
width: 150 ,
top: 120
});
view_car_3.add(label_car_3);

Ti.UI.currentWindow.add(view_car_3);
```

Does anyone know how to make the text appear in the table niveau 4?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

first and for most...if you put all your files under resources folder then no need to give whole path...so do follow...

```
var data = [
{title:'Niveau 2', hasChild:true, dest:'Car_1.js'},
{title:'Niveau 3', hasChild:true, dest:'Car_2.js'},
{title:'Niveau 4', hasChild:true, dest:'Car_3.js'}
];
```

and variable is dest not url so you need to change this in table click event

```
table.addEventListener('click', function(e){
if (e.rowData.hasChild) {
    var newWin = Ti.UI.createWindow({

    url: e.rowData.dest,
    title:  e.rowData.title,
    backgroundColor: '#DCE6F2'
});
```

Comment: welcome.remember that we can not access any files from outside of our project so whenever you need to access files then only put that under project folder and set path according to your current window.